# Rest Api: When to use Post, PUT, PATCH and Delete

Tags: rest, http-post, http-delete, http-method, http-put

I am working on a restful api and I need to update a resource (i.e. a customer detail record with 10 fields).

On Add request, I send a Post request with complete record. 
On update request, I send a PUT request with complete record of 10 fields. 
On Verify request, I send a PUT request with just two fields i.e. recordId and versionNo.
On Delete request, I send a DELETE request with two fields in HttpOptions.

I have few questions that:

- Although, it a restful api but specific application which would be used by an angular application, So should I return data in response of POST/PUT requests.
- Should I use PATCH in case of Verify (or anyother action where just recordId and versionNo send to server to change some fields) or it is OK to use PUT.
- To make uniformity, should I send data in body of delete request as I need recordId and versionNo to delete a record.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Should I use PATCH in case of Verify (or anyother action where just
>   recordId and versionNo send to server to change some fields) or it is
>   OK to use PUT.

In RESTful API designs, PUT requests are generally used to add or replace an entire resource, whereas a PATCH should be just used to update an existing resource. A PUT request is called "idempotent" - no matter how many times you send a PUT response, you should get the same result. A PATCH is not idempotent.

example:

PATCH /Cars/vauxhall-astra/engine --> This request would be used to only update the engine of my already existing vauxhall astra

PUT /Cars/renault-clio --> This request would create a new Renault Clio or, if it already exists, replace the entire Clio using the data specified in my request. A Clio would then be guaranteed to exist after my request is successful, regardless of whether it existed or not before.

> Although, it a restful api but specific application which would be used by an angular application, So should I return data in response of POST/PUT requests.

Totally up to you, returning data from a POST/PUT is fine - especially if it saves you having to make extra GET api requests. Just always make sure you are only ever returning the data you need from a response.

> To make uniformity, should I send data in body of delete request as I need recordId and versionNo to delete a record.

Again it's totally up to you. Whether you use query parameters (e.g. DELETE cars?id=123) or a request body is just your preference, there's nothing in REST that has rules for this.

Comment: PATCH is not idempotent. Does it mean, when a PATCH request is made, api update it iff the resource exists. If resource doesn't exist, it will not update the resource.

Comment: Yes that's correct. Remember that idempotency means the same request should always produce the same result. A PATCH cannot be idempotent, because imagine you send a PATCH request that changes the location of a resource. If you sent through the exact same PATCH request through again it would fail because the location has since changed.

Comment: In my case, a PATCH request only be made when a record exists and a verify action is available. So in this scenario, it would be safe to use PATCH, instead of PUT, while I just need to update statusCode of that particular record.

Comment: Yeah, you should use PATCH in this situation

Answer (score 2):

#### REST Response

A RESTful API **MUST** always answer with HTTP codes to client requests:

> Success and error responses are a vital part to define how an API is used correctly.

Refer to [**this**](https://opensource.zalando.com/restful-api-guidelines/) guide to solve all your RESTful related questions.

---

#### PATCH/PUT

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patch_verb#PUT_vs_PATCH_vs_POST):

> The main difference between the PUT and PATCH method is that the PUT method uses the request URI to supply a modified version of the requested resource which replaces the original version of the resource whereas the PATCH method supplies a set of instructions to modify the resource. If the PATCH document is larger than the size of the new version of the resource sent by the PUT method **then the PUT method is preferred**.

Also:

> Using the PUT method consumes more bandwidth as compared to the PATCH method when only a few changes need to be applied to a resource. But when the PATCH method is used, it usually involves fetching the resource from the server, comparing the original and new files, creating and sending a diff file. On the server side, the server has to read the diff file and make the modifications. This involves a lot of overhead compared to the PUT method.[11] On the other hand, the PUT method requires a GET to be performed before the PUT and it is difficult to ensure that the resource is not modified between the GET and PUT requests.

So I will use *PATCH* for verifying a resource.

---

#### DELETE

Normaly, for *DELETE* requests, the client specifies the `id` of the resource and pass it as a *Path Variable* on the URL:

```
curl -X DELETE http://example.com/resource/{id}
```

But you can pass a body on the request also. This possibility is stated by MDN Mozilla Web DOCS:

> Request has body   -   **May**
>
> Successful response has body   -   May